# jQuery Tools Tabs + History - Preventing jumping in IE 6 and 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-tools

I'm making use of the jQuery Tabs plugin along with the "History" plugin, to allow bookmarking and use of the browser back button. Everything works great - except in IE 6 and 7. When you load the page, IE jumps down to the anchors.

Here's the example implementation: http://coolkidz.com/sell-consign/

Any ideas to get IE to behave nicely?

Comment: you didn't notice IE gave your js error? Line 41, char 6

Comment: also, line 1, char 1 in jquery.tools.min.js. i think you should fix those error first

Comment: for what it's worth, your page also looks broken in Firefox 3.6 (and yes, there are still people using it, despite Mozilla's best efforts)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! I'll take a look for those errors.

Comment: @Shadow_boi - What version of IE are you seeing that in? I've tested IE6 and IE7 and don't see any errors (at least not via Browserstack).

Comment: i tried it in IEtester (IE7 and IE8)

Comment: @Shadow_boi: Use of IETester is not recommended, It always blocks your javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the History tool is enabled in IE 6/7, it adds a hidden iframe to the page and initially sets the iframe's `location.hash` to `'#'`. When this happens, IE scrolls to the iframe (even though is it hidden), which is at the bottom of the page.

Without being able to edit the jQuery Tools source, I can think of two workarounds:

1. Add this JavaScript before you initialize jQuery Tools Tabs ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/2Hnu8/3/)):

   ```
   if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < '8') {
       $(window).one("hash", function(e, h) {
           if (h === '#') {
               $(window).scrollTop(0);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   This scrolls to the top of the page after the History tool is initialized. The down side to this workaround is that if the window wasn't at the top of the page, IE would have stayed at the correct position, but this forces it to scroll to the top.
2. Add this CSS ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/2Hnu8/2/)):

   ```
   iframe {
       position: absolute;
   }​
   ```

   IE doesn't try to scroll to a `position: absolute` iframe. The down side to this workaround is that this affects any other iframes on your page.

I suggest going with workaround #1.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I will test it and report back!

Comment: That JS fix really seems like it should work - It's causing some jumping around though. I opted for the iframe fix, though, which is brilliant thinking. I went ahead and targetted the iframe inside the .inner div and left the targetting specifically to IE7 and IE6. It works beautifully!

Comment: I spoke too soon.. IE was tricking me. I was refreshing to test and, given that I was already scrolled to the top, it appeared to be working. The best way to test is to click the links from http://coolkidz.com/about and then follow those over. #1 is "working", but the jumping effect and refreshing of the screen that happens on the end-user side isn't going to cut it. I'll test further.